# ProcessException: Found candidates, but lacked sufficient permissions to execute getting this error while running flutter application Ubuntu linux

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart, gradle

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTSrp.png)
How to resolve this error in ubuntu